# How do connect to soap/rest datasource using sharepoint designer 2013?

Tags: wcf

How do I connect to **SOAP/REST** data-source using SharePoint Designer 2013? (my web service is `https://mysite/service/v2/soap.php?wsdl` Using the **External Content Type** directly for a **WCF** service does not work.

Is there a work-around for this?